# function template parameters with two different types, order changes works

Tags: c++, templates

This is about templates and their arguments deduction. Templates parameters are deduced from function parameters if they can. Consider this example:

```
template <class D, class T>
T Max(D, double);

template <class D, class T>
T Max(D a, double b) {
  return (a>b ? a : b); 
}   

int main() {
  std::cout << Max<double>(1,2.1) << std::endl;
}
```

I expected it to work on the basis of that Max's first parameter would be deduced to int, which would go to D and Max's second parameter is explicitly given as double. And since I want double to return, wouldn't it to template parameter 'T'? I expected compiler to work here. Instead, it gave:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘Max(int, double)’
```

However, I, then changed the order and made the program as:

template 
    T Max(D, double);

```
template <class T, class D>
T Max(D a, double b) {
  return (a>b ? a : b);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << Max<double>(1,2.1) << std::endl;
}
```

AND IT WORKED.

What is the minimal thing I missed. Does it mean that only first template parameter should be used as return value of function templates.

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
Max<double>(1,2.1)
```

of the following template function

```
template <class D, class T>
T Max(D a, double b) {
  return (a>b ? a : b); 
}
```

you explicitly specified that the template parameter D has the type double. So it is the type of the first function parameter, But you specified nothing for the template parameter T. And the compiler is unable to determine the type of the template parameter T in the function call expression.

You could write for example

```
std::cout << Max<double, double>(1,2.1) << std::endl;
```

specifying that the template type parameter T has the type double.

For this declaration

```
template <class T, class D>
T Max(D a, double b) {
  return (a>b ? a : b);
}
```

the compiler using this expression

```
Max<double>(1,2.1)
```

can deduce the type parameter D to the type int. The template argument `double` is used for the template type parameter T.

The order of template arguments corresponds to the order of template parameters.